# Vector Grid shows big difference between cartesian and ellipsoid measurement

Tags: vector-grid, qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.4.1 on Windows 10. Project CRS is EPSG:3857 (WGS 84/Pseudo-Mercator).

I have defined a vector grid. Type is Rectangle (polygon). Horizontal and vertical distance is 50 m. Overlay is 0 m. GRID CRS is EPSG:3857. This goes well. But after selecting one of the polygons, the Cartesian properties are quite different from the Ellipsoid properties:
- Cartesian: Outline: 200 m, Area 2500 m2
- Ellipsoid: Outline: 122,536, Area 938,435 m2
- Using the measurement tool shows sides of the rectangle of 30,567 m.

I expected a small difference between Cartesian and Ellipsoid outcomes, but this is impossible.

Does anybody have a clue of what is going wrong?

Comment: where about are you testing, try nearer the equator for a better answer

Comment: My application area is The Netherlands

Comment: too far North for Pseudo-Mercator to be anything like correct.

Comment: The scale factor increases in a [Mercator projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) as you move away from the Equator. At 52° latitude it is approximately equal to sec(52°) = 1.62 meaning that your distances in epsg 3857 will be around 1.62 times greater than reality. I suggest you use a map projection better suited for your area of interest, that would minimize distortions and give you better results if you wish to do 2D math on your map.

Comment: For the Netherlands, try one of the Amersfoort based projections, or ETRS89 / UTM zone 31N

Comment: Thank you all for explanations and suggestions. I understand the increasing scale factor in Mercator projecten. But I expected, when defining a grid in QGIS explicitely in EPSG:3857, it would result in a correct grid within EPSG:3857. I left it that way and followed your suggestions and now use Amersfoort/RD New projections. Problem solved.